# Which Version of VS2012 or VS2013 good for Sharepoint 2013 to Development Enviornment?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-2013

AS i have been trying to develop WEB PART in Visual Studio . As i need your aid to develop Sharepoint Solution for Sharepoint 2013.

I have installed SP2013 on window server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2012 on the server machine. I need to know , either VS2013 or VS2012 have to install on the server to develop Sharepoint solution?

I am looking forward your valuable answer. I have searched it a lot in Google about this requirement but I didn't get clear content. So I am awaiting your answer to make me to develop Sharepoint webpart solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both `VS 2012` and `VS 2013`are intended for creating SharePoint 2013 applications

But `Visual Studio 2013` introduces some enhanced features for SharePoint:

- **MVC support**. You can use the new MVC (model-view-controller) pattern
  in Office and SharePoint 2013 to create apps. In apps for SharePoint,
  you can choose the ASP.NET MVC Web Application as the web app for
  your project. You can also publish apps to Windows Azure websites.
- **Cloud Business App project template**. Create line of business applications hosted on SharePoint for Office 365 that are based on
  Visual Studio LightSwitch technologies.
- **App Packaging and Publishing**. The packaging and publishing process for apps for SharePoint and apps for Office has been
  streamlined and improved. An updated publishing dialog box enables
  you to provide all the information needed to publish your app to a
  target location. It also connects you to the Seller Dashboard, which
  enables you to submit your app to the Office Store. See [How to:
  Publish an app for SharePoint by using Visual Studi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/jj220044.aspx)o and [How to:
  Publish an app for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179811.aspx).
- **Add search capabilities to your apps for SharePoint**. You can deploy custom search configurations to a search-enabled site. See [How
  to: Deploy custom search configurations by using Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/dn194077.aspx).
- **Debug remote event receivers and remote workflows**. Remote event receivers and workflows contained in apps for SharePoint now support
  full debugging. See [Developing apps for SharePoint on a remote
  system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220047.aspx).

Source: [What's New in Visual Studio 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx#bkmk_sharepoint)

Answer (score 0):

This article clearly states that you can use Visual Studi 2012

Start: Set up the development environment for SharePoint 2013
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869.aspx

However, there is no harm in using VS 2013 if you have the license for it.

Comment: Thank you for reply . which of the follwowing application i have to install vs_ultimate.exe , vs_premium.exe ,vs_professional.exe?

Comment: vs_ultimate.exe should be fine

Comment: ok. but in many websites seems to be ,if want to install SP2013 with VS2012 , you need to have 10GB RAM.  but i have 8GB RAM is this enough ?